# Promises - How to make asynchronous code execute synchronous without async / await?

Tags: javascript, asynchronous, promise, async-await

```
  var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    setTimeout(() => resolve("first"), 5000);
  });
  var p2 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    setTimeout(() => resolve("second"), 2000);
  });
  var p3 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
    setTimeout(() => resolve("third"), 1000);
  });

  console.log("last to print");

p1.then(()=>p2).then(()=>p3).then(()=> console.log("last to be printed"))
```

As I was reading about promises, I know that I can print promises synchronous (in this case print: first, second, third, last to print) when I use async /await. Now I have also been reading that the same thing can be achieved using .then chaining and async/await is nothing 'special'. When I try to chain my promises, however, nothing happens except for the console.log of "last to be printed". Any insight would be great! Thanks!!

Edit to question:

```
  var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("first"), 5000);
    resolve("first resolved")
  });
  var p2 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("second"), 2000);
    resolve("second resolved")
  });
  var p3 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => console.log("third"), 0);
    resolve("third resolved")
  });

  console.log("starting");
  p1.then((val) => {
    console.log("(1)", val)
    return p2
  }).then((val) => {
    console.log("(2)", val)
    return p3
  }).then((val) => {
    console.log("(3)", val)
  })
```

Loggs:

```
starting
(1) first resolved
(2) second resolved
(3) third resolved
third
second
first
```

1: if executor function passed to new Promise is executed immediately, before the new promise is returned, then why are here promises resolved ()synchronously) first and after the setTimeouts (asynchronously) gets executed?

2. Return value vs. resolve promise:

   var sync = function () {
     return new Promise(function(resolve, reject){
         setTimeout(()=> {
           console.log("start")
           resolve("hello") //--works
         // return "hello" //--> doesnt do anything
         }, 3000);
       })
     }
     sync().then((val)=> console.log("val", val))

Comment: How do you know nothing else is happening?

Comment: All three promises are executing independently, they're not chained at all.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The executor function you pass to `new Promise` is executed **immediately**, before the new promise is returned. So when you do:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
  setTimeout(() => resolve("first"), 5000);
});
```

...by the time the promise is assigned to `p1`, the `setTimeout` has **already** been called and scheduled the callback for five seconds later. That callback happens whether you listen for the resolution of the promise or not, and it happens whether you listen for resolution via the `await` keyword or the `then` method.

So your code starts three `setTimeouts` **immediately**, and then starts waiting for the first promise's resolution, and only then waiting for the second promise's resolution (it'll already be resolved, so that's almost immediate), and then waiting for the third (same again).

To have your code execute those `setTimeout` calls only sequentially when the previous timeout has completed, you have to not create the new promise until the previous promise resolves (using shorter timeouts to avoid lots of waiting):

```js
console.log("starting");
new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
  setTimeout(() => resolve("first"), 1000);
})
.then(result => {
    console.log("(1) got " + result);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
      setTimeout(() => resolve("second"), 500);
    });
})
.then(result => {
    console.log("(2) got " + result);
    return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {  
      setTimeout(() => resolve("third"), 100);
    });
})
.then(result => {
    console.log("(3) got " + result);
    console.log("last to print");
});
```

Remember that a promise doesn't do anything, and doesn't change the nature of the code in the promise executor. **All** a promise does is provide a means of observing the result of something (with really handy combinable semantics).

Let's factor out the common parts of those three promises into a function:

```
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}
```

Then the code becomes a bit clearer:

```js
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}

console.log("starting");
delay(1000, "first")
.then(result => {
    console.log("(1) got " + result);
    return delay(500, "second");
})
.then(result => {
    console.log("(2) got " + result);
    return delay(100, "third");
})
.then(result => {
    console.log("(3) got " + result);
    console.log("last to print");
});
```

Now, let's put that in an `async` function and use `await`:

```js
function delay(ms, ...args) {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
        setTimeout(resolve, ms, ...args);
    });
}

(async() => {
    console.log("starting");
    console.log("(1) got " + await delay(1000, "first"));
    console.log("(2) got " + await delay(500, "second"));
    console.log("(3) got " + await delay(100, "third"));
    console.log("last to print");
})();
```

Promises make that syntax possible, by standardizing how we observe asynchronous processes.

---

Re your edit:

> 1: if executor function passed to new Promise is executed immediately, before the new promise is returned, then why are here promises resolved ()synchronously) first and after the `setTimeouts` (asynchronously) gets executed?

There are two parts to that question:

A) *"...why are here promises resolved ()synchronously) first..."*

B) *"...why are here promises resolved...after the `setTimeouts` (asynchronously) gets executed"*

The answer to (A) is: Although you resolve them synchronously, `then` *always* calls its callback asynchronously. It's one of the guarantees promises provide. You're resolving `p1` (in that edit) before the executor function returns. But the way you're observing the resolutions ensures that you *observe* the resolutions in order, because you don't start observing `p2` until `p1` has resolved, and then you don't start observing `p3` until `p2` is resolved.

The answer to (B) is: They don't, you're resolving them synchronously, and then observing those resolutions asynchronously, and since they're already resolved that happens very quickly; later, the timer callbacks run. Let's look at how you create `p1` in that edit:

```
var p1 = new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
  setTimeout(() => console.log("first"), 5000);
  resolve("first resolved")
});
```

What happens there is:

1. `new Promise` gets called
2. It calls the executor function
3. The executor function calls `setTimeout` to schedule a callback
4. You immediately resolve the promise with `"first resolved"`
5. `new Promise` returns and the resolved promise is assigned to `p1`
6. Later, the timeout occurs and you output `"first"` to the console

Then later you do:

```
p1.then((val) => {
  console.log("(1)", val)
  return p2
})
// ...
```

Since `then` always calls its callback asynchronously, that happens asynchronously — but **very soon**, because the promise is already resolved.

So when you run that code, you see all three promises resolve **before** the first `setTimeout` callback occurs — because the promises aren't waiting for the `setTimeout` callback to occur.

You may be wondering why you see your final `then` callback run before you see `"third"` in the console, since both the promise resolutions and the `console.log("third")` are happening asynchronously but **very soon** (since it's a `setTimeout(..., 0)` and the promises are all pre-resolved): The answer is that promise resolutions are *microtasks* and `setTimeout` calls are *macrotasks* (or just "tasks"). All of the microtasks a task schedules are run as soon as that task finishes (and any microtasks that they schedule are then executed as well), before the next task is taken from the task queue. So the task running your script does this:

1. Schedules a task for the `setTimeout` callback
2. Schedules a microtask to call `p1`'s `then` callback
3. When the task ends, its microtasks are processed:

   1. The first `then` handler is run, scheduling a microtask to run the second `then` handler
   2. The second `then` handler runs and schedules a micro task to call the third `then` handler
   3. Etc. until all the `then` handlers have run
4. The next task is picked up from the task queue. It's probably the `setTimeout` callback for `p3`, so it gets run and `"third"` appears in the console

> 2. Return value vs. resolve promise:

The part you've put in the question doesn't make sense to me, but your comment on this does:

> I read that returning a value or resolving a promise is same...

What you've probably read is that returning a value **from `then` or `catch`** is the same as returning a resolved promise **from `then` or `catch`**. That's because `then` and `catch` create and return **new promises** when they're called, and if their callbacks return a simple (non-promise) value, they resolve the promise they create with that value; if the callback returns a promise, they resolve or reject the promise they created based on whether that promise resolves or rejects.

So for instance:

```
.then(() => {
    return 42;
})
```

and

```
.then(() => {
    return new Promise(resolve => resolve(42));
})
```

have the same end result (but the second one is less efficient).

Within a `then` or `catch` callback:

1. Returning a non-promise resolves the promise `then`/`catch` created with that value
2. Throwing an error (`throw ...`) rejects that promise with the value you throw
3. Returning a promise makes `then`/`catch`'s promise resolve or reject based on the promise the callback returns

Comment: Thank you. I wonder: if the executor function passed to new Promise is executed immediately before promise is returned, why even using promises?

Comment: @javascripting - Because they provide standard semantics for observing the results of operations, typically asynchronous ops. In general, the promise executor function is used to do exactly what you're using it for: *Starting* an asynchronous process (in your case, `setTimeout`) that will complete later. Standard semantics rather than 18 different styles of callback APIs mean operations can be chained together in a consistent way, in series or in parallel, and enables useful things like `async` functions and their `await` syntax to simply coding. I've added to the answer to highlight that.

Comment: More on `async`/`await` [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/async_function).

Comment: Thanks a lot for taking the time to explain. Can I ask: I added an edit to my question, could you please explain why in that case the promises are resolved before the setTimeouts are executed? Also, I read that returning a value or resolving a promise is same, but (2nd in the edit), only when I resolve values, can I use that in my following .then, not by returning a value. Why is that? Thanks!!!!

Comment: @javascripting - I've updated the answer to address the edit.

Comment: Thanks soo much for this really clear answer!!!!! To my last question about return vs returning promise: In my code - when i dont resolve "hello" but return "hello" instead -my console.log("val", val) doesnt do anything. neither does "val" get logged to the console, not the value val

Comment: @javascripting - There's a big difference between the promise executor function and a `then`/`catch` callback. The return value of a promise executor is completely ignored. To resolve the promise, you must call `resolve`. (Whereas -- and this is a bit inconsistent -- if you `throw` from the promise executor, it rejects the promise, just like it does in a `then` or `catch` handler.)

Answer (score 6):

You cannot make asynchronous code execute synchronously.

Even `async` / `await` are just syntax that gives you a synchronous-style control flow *inside* a promise.

> When I try to chain my promises, however, nothing happens except for the console.log of "last to be printed". Any insight would be great!

The other functions don't generate any output. That has nothing to do with them being in promises.

You start three timers (all at the same time), then log 'last to print', then chain some promises so that 'last to be printed' will print when all three promises resolve (5 seconds after you start them all going).

If you want the timers to run sequentially, then you have to initiate them only when the previous one has finished, and if you want to see what they resolve with then you have to write code that actually looks at that.

```js
function p1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("first"), 5000);
  });
}

function p2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("second"), 2000);
  });
}

function p3() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("third"), 1000);
  });
}

function log(value) {
  console.log("Previous promise resolved with " + value);
}

p1()
  .then(log)
  .then(p2)
  .then(log)
  .then(p3)
  .then(log)
  .then(() => console.log("last to be printed"));
```

Async/await is, arguably, neater:

```js
function p1() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("first"), 5000);
  });
}

function p2() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("second"), 2000);
  });
}

function p3() {
  return new Promise(function(resolve, reject) {
    setTimeout(() => resolve("third"), 1000);
  });
}

function log(value) {
  console.log("Previous promise resolved with " + value);
}

(async function() {
  log(await p1());
  log(await p2());
  log(await p3());
  console.log("last to be printed");
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

If you need to call an await but the function that contains that await doesn't have to be async, because you need, for example, a "number" and not a "Promise number ", you can do de next:

```
var ex: number = new Number(async resolve => {
              var f = await funcionExample();                  
              resolve(f);
            }).valueOf();
```